# PHP byte serving PDF with fast web view

Tags: php, internet-explorer, pdf, web, adobe-reader

I have a large PDF file, and host in PHP server.

The PDF is "fast web view" enabled. I want user see the page 1 asap the PDF is start loading.
Refer to the solution from : http://www.coneural.org/florian/papers/04_byteserving.php

I refer to the solution to build a demo.

```
<?php
include_once('pdfbyteserve.php');
byteserve('pdf/sample_large.pdf');
?>
```

It is working in Chrome and Firefox, it display the page 1 asap, and continue to load.
But the IE 8 display keep loading and loading, and finally display this error too:
[image]
I understand this may the Adobe Reader problem, can I fix it? because most of my user is using IE 8 + Adobe Reader XI.

---

I have no idea what is going on, I am a fool in web development.
anyway I compare the apache log between IE and Chrome.

---

apache access log when IE request the page.

```
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 24821 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 8200 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 16392 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 2568 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 2056 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 16392 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 16392 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 14344 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 13832 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 16392 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 16392 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 16392 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 16392 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 4616 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 16392 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 16392 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 4616 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 16392 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 16392 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:05 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 17850249 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 4104 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 16392 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 16392 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 16392 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 3080 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 4616 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 1032 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 15368 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 16392 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 4104 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 4616 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 16392 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 16392 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 4104 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 4616 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 16392 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 16392 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 4616 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 4104 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 16392 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 16392 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 4616 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 2568 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 1544 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 16392 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 16392 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 520 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 4104 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 4356 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 16392 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 16392 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 7940 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:10:58:07 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 16392 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3)"
```

---

apache access log when Chrome request the page.

```
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:12 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 17850249 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:19 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 32776 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:19 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 1451090 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:19 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 32776 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:19 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 32776 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 32776 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 32776 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 32776 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 32776 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 32776 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 32776 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 32776 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 65544 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 65544 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 65544 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 65544 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 65544 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 65544 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 65544 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 65544 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 65544 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 65544 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 131080 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 131080 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 131080 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 131080 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 131080 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 131080 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 131080 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 131080 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 131080 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 131080 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 262152 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 262152 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 262152 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 262152 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 262152 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 262152 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 262152 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 262152 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 262152 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 262152 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:21 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 524296 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:22 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 524296 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:22 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 524296 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:22 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 524296 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:22 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 524296 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:22 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 524296 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:22 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 524296 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:23 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 524296 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:23 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 524296 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:23 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 524296 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:23 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 1048584 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:23 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 1048584 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:23 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 1048584 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:23 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 1048584 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [16/Jul/2014:11:08:23 +0800] "GET /PhpProject1/index.php HTTP/1.1" 206 2046783 "http://localhost/PhpProject1/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36"
```

---

I observed that, both IE and Chrome will get 200 first and then 206.
200 with the total filesize (in my case is about 17MBytes)
then with a series of 206, with the partial size, the partial size pattern is different, why?

---

Now, I just use the netbeans debugger to trace what is going on, when using IE 8, the Adobe Reader error will popup when running this code:

```
else{
    //no byteserving
    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
    header("Content-Length: $filesize");
    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    readfile($filename);
}
```

I still trying to understand what is the problem......

Comment: Comment from [@DanielMayer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3993602/daniel-mayer): I got it to work in Chrome and Firefox as well, and in IE as long as Acrobat Reader is installed, but not in Safari, not on mobile safari and not on Android. Did you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WHAT A FOOL I AM!!!!!

```
xxxxxxxxx<?php
include_once('pdfbyteserve.php');
byteserve('pdf/sample_large.pdf');
?>
```

Finally, I discover my demo fail, because my demo code send extra spaces (XXXXXXXX), which corrupt the pdf. I am very sorry and regret I waste a whole day.

Comment: ,It will really help me a lot if you can share pdfbyteserve.php or the range header logic because I had tried similar way(video streaming logic) but  it is not working some how.

Comment: @SmitShah I just using the code from http://www.coneural.org/florian/papers/04_byteserving.php

Comment: Thanks for the replay.I'd implemented this function I am not sure why it is always taking 200 status code instead of 206.I'd checked several threads but no where written that how can I implement 206 without using external PDF reader plugin.